# parser json with jquery and catch some values on the ayyas

Tags: jquery, html, json

I will catch some values from JSON file that they are not in same Object, but have same name

I have one Array:wallsListShShow that it have
   two Arrays too: wall1 and wall2
I could read name of wall1 and wall2, 
but I couldn't read `amoung`'s data.

```
{
    "wallsListShShow":[
        {   
            "wall1":[   
                {
                    "dateOrder" :"20190825121123",
                    "amoung"    :"13000"
                },{
                    "dateOrder" :"20190825121124",
                    "amoung"    :"400"
                },{
                    "dateOrder" :"20190825121125",
                    "amoung"    :"200"
                },{
                    "dateOrder" :"20190825121126",
                    "amoung"    :"100"
                }
            ],
            "wall2":[
                {
                    "dateOrder" :"20190825121117",
                    "amoung"    :"13000"
                },{
                    "dateOrder" :"20190825121118",
                    "amoung"    :"400"
                },{
                    "dateOrder" :"20190825121119",
                    "amoung"    :"400"
                },{
                    "dateOrder" :"20190825121120",
                    "amoung"    :"100"
                }
            ] // end of wall2
        }
    ] // end of wallsListShShow
}
```

--- jquery code

```
$.getJSON("json/datas.json",function(data){
      $.each(data.wallsListShShow,function(i,w){
        wallAmoungs.push(w.amoung);
        $.each(w, function(wallets, w){
          $('div.appData').append(""+
                                  "<div class='cardRow'>"+
                                    "<div class='iconDiv'>"+
                                       "<span>&#8512;</span>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "<h6>"+wallets+"</h6>"+
                                    "<p class='curentyAmoung'>"+
                                     -- amoungs ---     
                                   +"</p>"+
                                  " </div>");
        });
      });
    });
```

when i use w[0] or JSON.stringify(w[0]) or ...I just get errors.
I will get total of all `amoung`s in every two arrays, and show it in -- amoungs --.

Answer (score 0):

You should have unique name for your nested array operation. Please check modified code.

```
$.getJSON("json/datas.json",function(data){
      $.each(data.wallsListShShow,function(i,w){
        wallAmoungs.push(w);
        $.each(w, function(wallets, wa){
          $('div.appData').append(""+
                                  "<div class='cardRow'>"+
                                    "<div class='iconDiv'>"+
                                       "<span>&#8512;</span>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "<h6>"+wallets+"</h6>"+
                                    "<p class='curentyAmoung'>"+
                                     wa.amoung     
                                   +"</p>"+
                                  " </div>");
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Why I did that???? that was my mistake. but when I changed to your code, again I catch "undefined" ?

Comment: Remove double quotes form your JOSN on terms 'wallsListShShow' and 'wall1', 'wall2'. Make sure that your JOSN file readed by your code.